# C++ program produced many errors

Tags: c++

Ok, I'm a complete C++ noob (I only started learning yesterday) and I am trying to write a simple calculator program. I wrote it in notepad, but when i tried to compile it, the cmd produced so many errors it was funny. Can anybody tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;




int main()
{
double num1;
double num2;
string operator;
double num3;

cout<<"Enter your first number"<<endl;
cin<<num1;
cout<<"Enter the operator"<<endl;
cin<<operator;
cout<<"Enter the next number"<<endl;
cin<<num2;

if(operator=="/"&&num2==0)
{
cout<<"You are attempting to divide by 0. This is impossible and causes the destruction of the universe. However, the answer is infinity"<<endl;
}


if(operator=="+")
{
num3 = num1+num2;
}
else if(operator=="-")
{
num3 = num1-num2;
}
else if(operator=="*"||operator=="x"||operator=="X")
{
num3 = num1*num2;
}
else
{
num3 = num1/num2;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are the compiler errors you are getting? Did you ask for all warnings and debugging info?

Comment: `operator` is a reserved word in C++.

Comment: Next time please list the full text of at _least_ the first error.  If you're using Visual Studio, the full text is in the "Output" window; The "error" window only has summaries.

Comment: Come on guys, he used Notepad, he has no syntax highlighting, so he couldn't know that `operator` was reserved. Of course, using Notepad to write code is another issue altogether.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel Thanks :) Mooing duck, y are u commenting this now? I asked it ages ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`operator` is a keyword - use `op` for your variable name instead.

You want to input using the `>>` operator with `cin`, not the `<<` operator.

Answer (score 3):

Main error is that `operator` is a keyword in C++, you can't use it as a variable name. Try renaming it to `op` or something. Compilers often get confused, just concentrate on the first couple of errors, fix those and recompile.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely this line:

```
string operator;
```

`operator` is a C++ keyword. Try changing it for some other name, like `userOp`.

Answer (score 0):

To read from a stream, you need >>, so it's cin>>num1;

Answer (score 0):

A. What are the errors?
B. As an advice for a noob (as you call yourself) when you writing a new code, try to compile it after each part you write, this will help you figure out which piece of code caused the error.